# VBA WHILE/WEND Loop Updating the Previous Row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, while-loop

I'm updating MS Access using a While/Wend loop based on a condition. The query seems to update the previous record in my table that *does not meet* the loop criteria and *does not update the actual record* that meets the criteria.

This section of the code has the identifier that i use to update Access:

```
Dim rr As Range
Set rr = [a2]
```

This section increments the row:

```
Dim r As Long 
r = 2
```

Now, I'm checking as long as the length in column A that contains the identifier is greater than zero, and the corresponding cell in column F contains a "Yes", execute the sql query:

```
While Len(Sheet2.Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
   If Sheet2.Range("F" & r).Value = "Yes" Then
      myid = rr.Offset(0, 0).Value
      qString = "UPDATE [table] SET [Status]= '" & statusvalue & "' WHERE [Key]='" & myid & "'"
      cn.Execute qString, dbFailOnError
   End If
   r = r + 1
Wend
```

The query updates the database fine, just that it updates the incorrect record. For example, if row 2 does not contain a "Yes" and row 3 does, the record on row 2 gets updated in the database instead of the record on row 3!
I think this has something to do with my loop, which i am not able to figure out.

Hoping someone out there can help!

Comment: Why do you use `myid` Offset with variable `rr` (=A2) and offset `0,0`?? That will always point `myid` to cell A2 in your code, no matter what number `r` currently is.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `myid` is always pointing to cell A2. If you want the loop to return the ID based on the current row, you need to change the row `myid = rr.Offset(0, 0).Value`.

Since `rr` points to A2 and `r` starts at value 2, maybe you need

```
myid = rr.Offset(r-1, 0).Value
```

Or initialise `r` with 1 and just do

```
myid = rr.Offset(r, 0).Value
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to look at my code. I will try your suggestions and revert.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it did not seem to work. It continued to update the previous value. It may be possible that i used it in the wrong place. I added your edited before "Wend".

Comment: I did manage to get it to work using a For Each loop. But, i'd be interested to learn the way you had in mind too.